# Can I enable I2C before first boot?

Tags: i2c

I want to enable the I2C interface, but without having to boot, login, and the whole `sudo raspi-config`.

I tried editing /boot/config.txt right after `sudo dd` the image to the disk, still in my main computer, and uncommented the `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` line.

Now, everytime I reboot, it's like the interface is disabled. The line is still uncommented, and `i2c-dev` is the only thing in the /etc/modules file. Now everytime I reboot, I have to do `sudo raspi-config` all over again to make it work.

Is it something about permissions? I don't know where to look for problems here.

**Edit as requested:**

I wrote aversion of the INA219 library in C++, INA uses i2c.

This is how you can try it:

`git clone http://github.com/regisin/pi_ina219cpp
make
./build/profiler`

The library works fine if I use the `sudo raspi-config` (not even trying the manual part), and ev en when rebooting it continues to work.

However, when I tried to edit the `/boot/config.txt` file, it only works if I do a `sudo modprobe i2c-dev` manually, after the boot.

**Edit 2:**

If you read the previous section you noticed I used modprobe. I looked into the `/usr/bin/raspi-config` file, and noticed that the i2c function does a few commands:

1 - uncomment or add `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` line to `/boot/config.txt`
2 - insert `i2c-dev` to the `/etc/modules`
3 - `dtparam i2c_arm=on`
4 - `modprobe i2c-dev`

What puzzles me is that after editing /boot/config.txt directly in the sd card from another machine, raspi-config does not work as expected. It's like some configuration is resetting at boot time. I guess I could work around this by doing modprobe when booting, but it does not sound like that's the intended behavior.

Comment: As far as I know that should have worked.  You need to edit your question and tell us why you don't think it is enabled and other relevant information such as Pi and operating system details.

Comment: `but without having to boot` ... i think that you have to run some sort of sofware ... you have to boot the RPi .... make your question clearer as to what you are actually asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information supplied seems contradictory.

You need to do two things to enable the I2C bus.

1. Edit `/boot/config.txt` and enable the device tree entry.
2. Add the line `i2c-dev` to `/etc/modules`.

I suspect you are not adding `i2c-dev` to `/etc/modules` prior to the first boot.

Comment: Great, it worked. I didn't know about `/etc/modules` before, then tried modifying after booted. Tried again with a fresh install and now it works.